# download data as JSON format from controller by get method in fullCalendar plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working with fullCalendar plugin and I have some problem with jQuery `get` method. I am downloading data from controller using JSON format and save those data to array `myData`. But I have a issue. If I run page with my fullCalendar plugin It seems that my `myData` array is empty until I click next/previous week button. I debugged it on browser and what is strange while i am run page with fullCalendar, `myData` array has correctly values and also calendar works as expected. I don't know what is going on and how can I address the issue.

here is my code:

```
@section scripts{
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment-timezone.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js"></script>

<script id="jsbin-javascript">

    var clickedEvents = [];

    var myData = [];

    var myEvents = [];

     //HERE WE GO:
     $.fn.myfunction = function () {
            $.get("/BookVisit/TakeBookedEvents/", function (data, status) {
                for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
                    myData.push(data[i].loginUser);
                }
            });
//with this alert all works good with first run page - 
//and events in array get css already-clicked class
            //alert('hej'); 
        };


    var timeCursor = moment(); 
    var endtime = +moment().add(5, 'days');
    while (+timeCursor < endtime) {
        var start = +timeCursor;
        timeCursor = timeCursor.add(15, 'minutes');
        var end = +timeCursor;
        myEvents.push({ start: start, end: end });
    }

    var eventRender = function (event, element) {
        $(element).html(moment(event.start).format('h:mm'));

        //Add class to event from array!
        if (myData.indexOf(event.start.format()) >= 0)
        {
            $(element).addClass('already-clicked');
            return element;
        }
        else {

            return element;
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $().myfunction();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            editable: false,
            allDaySlot: false,
            selectable: true,
            events: myEvents,
            eventColor: '#33CC33',
            timezone: 'UTC',
            eventRender: eventRender,
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

UPDATE:
I am expecting data in `myData` array before fullCalendar render events to calendar: `eventRender: eventRender,` .Because `var eventRender` function check if `event.start` value is in `myData` array and if it does that element get css class `already-clicked` which change color of this element in fullCalendar view.

In the picture You can see what is going on.
http://i1290.photobucket.com/albums/b532/wojtek_vtec/Prog/FC-2_zpsj0pjpgh5.jpg

Comment: Use developer tools (F12, Network Tab) within chrome to have a look at what exactly is being returned from your `$.get`, is there data coming back and is it in the expected format?

Comment: Yes, data is returning correctly in expected format and it all should works and It does but first I must click next/previous week button on fullCalendar plugin. If I don't change week to next nothing happens(It looks like `myData` array is empty) but in developer tools I see that array aleready has values.

Comment: Please can you update your question to make it a bit more clear.  At what point within your code are you expecting myData to have a value, but it doesn't?

Comment: Hey I updated what is my point. if You still don't understend what i want to achieve please let me know I try explain it again :)

Comment: Great, that's a bit more clear now. :)  Hopefully the answer I've given helps, let me know